# Triggering a selectedindexchanged event from from a master page on a content page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
   Public Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim comboIndex As Integer
    MsgBox(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)

    Dim ddl As DropDownList = Master.FindControl("cmbCulture")
    comboIndex = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex
    If ddl.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        'comboIndex = ddl.SelectedValue
    End If
    MsgBox(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex)

    comboIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

    Dim sqlQuery As String
    If comboIndex = 1 Then sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM scale WHERE scaleName = 'Major'"
    If comboIndex = 0 Then sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM scale WHERE scaleName = 'Dominant7'"
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM scale"
```

I need to know that I am triggering the selectedvaluechanged event of my dropdown list that is on my master page from my content page (default). I put a message box in the code so I will know that it has got there, but I can't get it to fire. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have done that before, what you can do is to make the method public, and then in the content page call the instance of the master and call the method  you need. This post should help you
http://geekswithblogs.net/diadiora/archive/2008/12/01/call-a-method-from-masterpage-in-content-page.aspx

Then in VB.NET would look something like
In the content page

```
Dim master As SiteMaster = DirectCast(Page.Master, SiteMaster)
master.Method1()
```

in the master page

```
Public Sub Method1()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the code. I need a solutions in vb.net. Maybe there is a way to easily translate this c# code, but I don't know.